# Cloud Run serverless eventing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

Cloud Run is related to the "serving"(HTTP) capability of Knative. Are there plans to implement the "eventing" capabilities? There a PubSub source for "eventing" but it needs to run on a k8s cluster we manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Run supports Pub/Sub as event source at the moment:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub